# не применяются миграции Laravel

Tags: laravel

Всем привет, скачал Laravel 5.8. При выполнении команды php artisan migrate не может соединиться с бд

mysql поднял на докере, через workbench захожу без проблем по этим данным

переименование на localhost не помогает php artisan config:cache

до этого помню устанавливал не было подобных проблем.. подскажите пожалуйста что можно придумать?

```html
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33062
DB_DATABASE=app
DB_USERNAME=app
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а внутри контейнера пробовали миграции накатывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовали docker-compose то при указании HOST надо указывать название контейнера, т.е вместо

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

Надо:

```
DB_HOST=freelara-mysql
```

Comment: все равно так же(

http://i.imgur.com/HmkfC2f.png
http://i.imgur.com/9WI8hpc.png

Comment: @lagavu попробуйте внутренний порт 3306, так как конект происходит внутри сети докерконтейнеров, а не из хост машины . Вот быстрый урок по развороту ларавел в докере: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TumfGqUf39U